# Interface casting

Tags: c#, interface

I have a few classes i can't change. They have one property `Prop3` in common:

```
public class c1
{
    public  string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public  string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public  string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class c2
{
    public  string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public  string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class c3
{
    public  string Prop5 { get; set; }
    public  string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to acces this property without knowing the type. I thought of using a Interface:

```
public interface ic
{
    string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

But this code throws a invalid cast exception:

```
c1 c1o = new c1() { Prop3 = "test" };
string res = ((ic)c1o).Prop3;
```

Comment: How do you not know the type though?

Comment: @DavidG `public string GetString(object item){ return ((ic)item).Prop3;}`

Comment: Then why not just have 3 overloads for that method that take in the actual class instead of objects?

Comment: My first thought was - mapping within one line instead of overloading this 3 times

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C# doesn't support compile-time [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), so if you can't change your types, no luck on that.

You can access your property using `dynamic`, which allows runtime duck-typing (no compile time checking though, and you lose intellisense if you use Visual Studio):

```
c1 c1o = new c1() { Prop3 = "test" };
string res = ((dynamic)c1o).Prop3;
```

Or via reflection:

```
c1 c1o = new c1() { Prop3 = "test" };
string res = (string)c1o.GetType().GetProperty("Prop3").GetValue(c1o);
```

Since there's no compile-time checking, you'll need to handle exceptions in case you pass an instance with no `Prop3`.

Or if the types are not sealed, you can try implementing your own derived types where you can specify an interface:

```
public interface ic
{
   string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class c1d : c1, ic {}
public class c2d : c2, ic {}
public class c3d : c3, ic {}
```

This would require you control the creation of the instances though, instances will need to be of type `c1d`, `c2d`, `c3d`, won't work if you get objects of type `c1`, `c2` or `c3`

You can do explicit type conversions as @David pointed out (which is a clever trick), but that means you'll have two instances of your object. For a very simple case like the one presented in the question, it might do... if you need anything more advanced, that might be quite tricky

Comment: This will throw an exception if you give it another type though.

Comment: @DavidG - Yes, it will, but I can't think of another way to do it.

Comment: @DavidG definitely, but not much more one can do here

Comment: @Enigmativity Was just giving that as an FYI, error checking could always be added. Another (evil) way would be a lot of if/else statements.

Comment: @DavidG yeah, I specified `dynamic` does *run-time* duck-typing. I've made the first sentence more clear by adding a "compile-time" remark :-)

Comment: The problem with this is that `dynamic` is *slow as hell*, and this would be a bad in terms of performance.

Comment: @Fabjan it's slow, but not **slow as hell**. It has the cost of the runtime checks, but it's definitely faster than non-properly cached reflection (which is often used in favour of dynamic, for I'd say no reason)

Comment: It also has the slowness of starting up the compiler and compiling the code at runtime... I would not solve this using `dynamic`.

Comment: It's hard to give a definitive answer to this problem with the simple presented problem (which is reading a string property for a `Console.Write`). What I'd do depends on the scenario... my more likely scenario would be wrapping those classes which I can't change with my own types if possible, but again, depends on the scenario: whether I'm controlling the creation of the instances, whether I'm using them in critical loops or in in huge collections, etc.

I'm not against `dynamic`, but as everything else, it must be used where it makes sense

Comment: Indeed, `dynamic` isn't too bad if you call the code many times, because the results of the compilation are cached so it isn't done multiple times. In fact, if you call it enough times the `dynamic` version can be faster than using normal reflection. It all depends on usage, as you say.

Answer (score 7):

Use an adapter-like construction to encapsulate the conversion logic. Of course the downside of this is that you have to modify the class when `c4` pops up.

```
public class Adapter {
    public Adapter(object c) {
        if (!(c is c1 || c is c2 || c is c3))
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        _c = c;
    }

    private readonly object _c;

    public string Prop3 {
        get {
            if (_c is c1) return ((c1)_c).Prop3;
            if (_c is c2) return ((c2)_c).Prop3;
            if (_c is c3) return ((c3)_c).Prop3;
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var c1o = new c1() { Prop3 = "test" };
var adapter1 = new Adapter(c1);
var res1 = adapter1.Prop3;

var c2o = new c2() { Prop3 = "test" };
var adapter2 = new Adapter(c2);
var res2 = adapter2.Prop3;
```

Comment: This is the best answer here (imho).

Answer (score 3):

Another way to approach this is to use reflection to get the value of the property with a specified name.

For example, write a simple helper method like this:

```
public static T GetProperty<T>(object obj, string name)
{
    return (T) obj.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(obj);
}
```

Then given the following unrelated classes:

```
public class C1
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class C2
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class C3
{
    public string Prop5 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class C4
{
    public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    public string Prop5 { get; set; }
}
```

you can access the `Prop3` properties like so:

```
object c1 = new C1 {Prop3 = "C1"};
object c2 = new C2 {Prop3 = "C2"};
object c3 = new C3 {Prop3 = "C3"};
object c4 = new C4();

Console.WriteLine(GetProperty<string>(c1, "Prop3")); //Prints C1
Console.WriteLine(GetProperty<string>(c2, "Prop3")); //Prints C2
Console.WriteLine(GetProperty<string>(c3, "Prop3")); //Prints C3
Console.WriteLine(GetProperty<string>(c4, "Prop3")); // Throws an exception.
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's an invalid cast.  `c1` doesn't implement the interface `ic`:

```
public class c1
{
    // ...
}
```

In order to cast, the objects would have to be legitimately polymorphic:

```
public class c1 : ic
{
    // ...
}
```

But if you genuinely *can't* change the class in any way, then the types aren't polymorphic and are entirely unrelated.  To change from one to the other you would need to manually convert:

```
public class someClass : ic
{
    string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

//...

c1 c1o = new c1() { Prop3 = "test" };
string res = (new someClass { Prop3 = c1o.Prop3 }).Prop3;
```

The example is, of course, very contrived.  But you get the idea.  Two completely unrelated types can't be cast from one to the other.  You'd have to convert them.

You *can* encapsulate this conversion in a variety of ways though.  A helper method, a factory, even an explicit conversion operator (which would allow the conversion you originally attempted)

```
public class someClass : ic
{
    string Prop3 { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator someClass(c1 c1o)
    {
        return new someClass { Prop3 = c1o.Prop3 };
    }
}

// which should allow this...
c1 c1o = new c1() { Prop3 = "test" };
string res = ((ic)c1o).Prop3;
```

Comment: I think the explicit conversion is a clever trick (and I have +1'ed), however it requires having two instances, one of them incomplete... as I noted on my answer, it works for simple things (like reading a string property), but might complicate things on more advanced scenarios

Comment: @Jcl: True, it should be used judiciously.  Type systems can get clunky any time someone is in a position where they "can't change the code".  In situations like that, I usually prefer a conversion layer between the code that can't be changed (which I treat as an external dependency) and the code I control (my domain code).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than dealing with reflection/dynamic and the pitfalls therein, your method could easily be split into 3 overloads:

```
public string GetString(c1 item){ return item.Prop3;} 
public string GetString(c2 item){ return item.Prop3;} 
public string GetString(c3 item){ return item.Prop3;}
```

Downside is a little bit of repeated code, but the upside is no exceptions and compile time type checking.

Comment: Nevermind, I've got a good idea who did it now, I guess revenge was on the cards haha

Comment: Haha well thanks for that. "Someone" went and downvoted a couple of my answers, so I'm guessing it was a minor revenge tactic.

Comment: at 30k i dont think -2 matters XD

Comment: Absolutely, I think the multiple -1 for the person downvoting is much bigger :)

Comment: @DavidG If someone serially downvotes a lot of your answers, the downvotes are automatically removed at some point.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I know that, this was only 2 or 3 though, I'm not really bothered if it gets reversed.